# How to extract a 32 character string out of a string in python?

Tags: python, string, substring

There are a lot of questions and answers for extracting sub-strings that are helpful but they do not answer my question nor are they the same.

I have a md5 hash (**32 continuous hexadecimal characters**) within a string, for example:

Example 1:

> Hi here is the hash: 1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc thank you!

Example 2:

> 1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc There is the hash! Thanks!

My question is how can I extract the hash out of this considering that the characters around the hash value may change and the hash will not be in the same location every time, hence the different examples.

SOLUTION: output = re.search('[0-9a-fA-F]{32}', input_str)

Comment: if you ask for Python, why do you add the grep tag? Also, what did you try?

Comment: Look for a continuous sequence of 32 chars that only contains `[a-zA-Z0-9]`. Otherwise, you should be a bit more specific, you can't auto extract something if it doesn't have a minimal pattern it meets.

Comment: Use a regular expression.

Comment: What have you tried ? Hint: use python re module, see more there: https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Comment: @MarounMaroun ..Hexadecimals are from in range [0-9a-fA-F]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import re

str1 = "Hi here is the hash: 1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc thank you!"
str2 = "1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc There is the hash! Thanks!"

def get_hash(input_str):
    output = re.search('[0-9a-fA-F]{32}', input_str)
    if output:
        return output.group(0)

print get_hash(str1)
print get_hash(str2)
```

Comment: what if there is some hash longer than 32 chars ? You get only part of this hash but you should skip it.

Comment: @furas: that's not defined by the question, I'd say.

Comment: The only hashes i will be dealing with are MD5 which are 32 characters long, however using this I am getting an error: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'. I am assuming this is because it is returning None?

Comment: Replying to my comment, Yes it is because it returns None just add some error handling.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a starter for you,

```
>>> s = 'Hi here is the hash: 1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc thank you!'
>>> def extract_hash(s, sz=32):
        m = re.search(r'\b[0-9a-fA-F]{%d}\b' % sz, s).group(0)
        if m:
            return m


>>> extract_hash(s)
'1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc'

>>> s = '1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc There is the hash! Thanks!'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> extract_hash(s)
'1a159f8cb5b29887efc124af4d2702dc'
```

This relies on the fact that hash is made of hexadecimal characters in the range of (0-9, A-F) and the length of the hash you provide.

EDIT:

Added default length of hash to be 32 if not provided as input.

Comment: You should put the length of the pattern in the regex (as `{32}`) because currently if something else matches before the hash, the hash is missed.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich, my assumption is that the hash came in between word boundaries and should only match with [0-9a-fA-F], that should prevent from matching any other characters from other strings, unless you have an example to prove your comments?

Comment: Well suppose the number 12 occurs earlier in the string in the unrelated text, then that matches and will be your group 0.